# Change EXT3 stride and stripe-width settings post-install on CentOS 5.3

Tags: linux, centos, rhel5, ext3

Is there a way to change the stride and stripe-width options on an ext3 file system under CentOS/RHEL 5.3?  There's no way to specify it via anaconda during installation that I saw, and while I see the -E option to tune2fs available under Ubuntu, I don't see it in the manpage on CentOS.  I did try to use the -E flag on CentOS and it rejects the flag as unknown if I try to use it.  Anyone have any way to do this short of reinstallation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it can be done only in install time:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Disk_Optimization

Answer (score 0):

Try using "tune2fs"